# Fixing a redirect with appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, dns

I want my "naked" url to redirect in this natural way

`abc.com/li => www.abc.com/li`

Now instead, the /li is redirecting to the / just because I use appengine and my DNS registrar is doing something like this. Is there a way to fix the redirect so that it behaves in a more natural way like it's expected? I think my setting appear normal / default as can be seen from the attached images. Can you help me?
[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: can you paste your DNS settings? I think there is something wrong at that level ..

Comment: @MicheleOrsi Yes, I use google apps and enom for my DNS and I can log into enom and copypaste my settings from there. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MicheleOrsi I inspected my DNS settings and the appear to be just default. I've pasted the info about my DNS so that you might see what's going on. THanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I try to give an answer! You should have a row with these informations:

```
www         ghs.google.com      CNAME (Alias)
```

do you have it?